# Ember view is not populating the updated values when using components

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a add all component that uses a checkbox that either selects all the options given or removes all of them.

The Add All component looks like this:
**HBS**:

```
<label>{{input id="checkbox"
            type="checkbox"
            checked=isChecked}}
            Add All</label>
```

**JS**:

```
App.AddAllComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  isChecked: false,
  addAll: function() {
            var self =this;
            var options = self.get('options');
            var optArray = options.toArray();
            var selected = self.get('selected');
            if (self.get('isChecked') === true){
              (selected.clear()).pushObjects(optArray);
            }else{
              selected.clear();
            }
          }.observes('isChecked'),
 });
```

I use it like this:

```
<div class="form-input col-md-2">
     <p class="form-input-title">List of Items</p>
     {{view "select2Select" 
       content=items
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.codeWithName"
       selection=item
       multiple=true
      }}
      {{add-all classNames='btn-group'
        options=items
        selected=item
      }}
</div>
```

The select2select view looks like this:

**JS**:

```
App.Select2SelectView = Ember.Select.extend(Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties, {
    classNames: ['form-control'],
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'processChildElements');
    },

    processChildElements: function() {
        this.$().select2({
            placeholder: this.get('placeholder')
        });
    },

    willDestroyElement: function () {
        this.$().select2("destroy");
    }
});
```

The Problem is that even though this works, the view is not updated with the selected content when I use the component(the select2select dropdown shows no values in the UI even though the content is being pushed into the model).Help would be much Appreciated.